If a 'fire temple' was built in a gigantic city, with many huge perpetual flames inside, how could they keep smoke from bothering non-worshippers?
This temple I'm imagining is in a massive and fairly densely packed city. Technically all manner of magic is available and I could answer "they use a spell to get rid of the smoke" but I'm looking for an answer which is hopefully more possible in the real world.
I'm thinking about the fact that in the real world buildings producing a lot of smoke just... let it into the air. Maybe this is because nobody is asking them to do better, or maybe this is because there isn't a good solution.
In the fantasy city in question, the government is very strict and would not like it if smoke was constantly rising from this temple and reducing air quality and comfort for everyone else. So I'm trying to think of an engineering way to make these fire temple guys in the clear.
One thought I've had was that smoke could be filtered or trapped somehow in big stacks, but how effective could that be really? How could you do that without the filters overheating from all the rising hot air?
Another thought was some way of cooling the air to make the smoke and ash fall back down, being somehow collected on the ground?
Or... pipes? Having the air flow inside the temple highly controlled somehow? I don't know.
Any ideas?

Someone already answered that it depends on the substance that they are burning A good cacndidate would whale oil. From my research for my project, it is a very substance for burning, it produces no smoke and a very bright light. Try to look into that.

Historical cities in the middle ages and much of the industrial era were just blanketed in smoke anyway.

@JackAidley  ... blanketed ... --> As is most of modern China and quite a lot of some parts of India :-( .  [[I've visited China many times. Smog is the norm anywhere, alas. India once. New Delhi was very bad - as was the countryside for many miles (brick kilns).

Sounds like the Ori and the City of Celestis in Stargate Atlantis. Their solution was to purge the unbelievers.

Portal at the end of the chimney, portal out in space

Ha ha thanks for the ideas everyone

It Depends on What They're Burning
Partial frame challenge: does there need to be smoke?
If they're burning coal or wood, then yes, smoke is a big problem that you'll have to address through ventilation or emissions scrubbing (depending on your technological level).
If they're burning methane, on the other hand, the combustion products are carbon dioxide and water vapour.  There can be carbon monoxide if insufficient oxygen is provided, but no smoke or ash.  If they're fortunate enough to have a source of hydrogen, they can burn that without even carbon dioxide, though the flames will be invisible and therefore not nearly as impressive.
Any pure (that is, no attached nitrogen groups or similar chemistry) hydrocarbon will, with sufficient oxygen, burn into pure carbon dioxide and water.  No smoke, no ash.  So maybe they have an enormous distillery to produce methanol to burn?
They'd get dinged on their emissions, but I'm skeptical that a setting with a Fire Temple is too concerned about global warming just yet.
Edit: the Asian Games torch in 2023 was pure methanol, and it looks like it would be right at home in a fire temple.  The interesting thing about that torch was that the methanol was produced from carbon capture, making the whole operation carbon-neutral, but as I said, I doubt your setting is too concerned with carbon emissions yet.

Wow cool idea. Hadn't considered that. My followup question, since I know next to nothing about methane, is what would be reasonably simple products/matter to acquire and put into said-distillery? And do you have any idea how much they'd really have to be producing to do that?
I love the concept. The reason I wanted a 'non-magic' answer is that I think anything which adds a little industry/supply chain into the fantasy world makes it more interesting as it creates more locations, and more character relationships for the economy of making it run.

@curious2220 "How much they'd need" is really dependent on "How many/how big are the flames".  And as any distiller can tell you, any source of sugar will do.
If you were burning the stuff constantly in enormous flames, you might need the output of a couple of big distilleries to keep it running.

It does offer the possibility of using ethanol instead, as "a libation to <insert Fire God's name>".  Of course, then some underpriests might get into the holy libation and get absolutely smashed out of their gourds, and have to be excommunicated.

Yeah I like this, this is interesting and I'm gonna go with it. Great ideas and I'm gonna call this answered. Thank you!

Hydrogen flames hard to see? A pinch of salt should do!

china had methane moved via bamboo pipes from natural gas veins, in 500bc,  used for boiling seawater.

Having a huge invisible bonfire sounds awesomely mystical!
Just imagine the human sacrifices burn from an invisible source of great heat!
Might have to keep your fuel sourcing secret to keep up the mystery tho :)

"If they're burning methane, on the other hand, the combustion products are carbon dioxide and water vapour. " - not true.  Burning methane in Earth atmosphere will also produce nitrous oxides if it gets hot enough - NO and NO2 - see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170988/how-does-burning-natural-gas-produce-nitrogen-oxides

Maybe the temple would have very tall smoke stacks shaped like light houses or minarats.  So the smoke would come out at the top, high above the city and float away in the air for a distance before descending to the levels of houses and streets.  Building towers hundreds of feet tall to discharge smoke and soot hundreds of feet high would be very impressive in a medieval society, but possible.
In London in the era of coal fires to heat houses and buildings, because the prevailing winds blew from the west, the wealthy lived in the West End, and the farther east people lived the more soot they got, so the worst slums were in the far east of London.
I note that jdulop's answer says:

They'd get dinged on their emissions, but I'm skeptical that a setting with a Fire Temple is too concerned about global warming just yet.

As a matter of fact there have been Zoroastrian fire temples for millennia.  And there are still some today, in a era when carbon emission is a hot topic.

As of 2021, there were 167 fire temples in the world, of which 45 were in Mumbai, 105 in the rest of India, and 17 in other countries.[6][7] Of these only nine (one in Iran and eight in India) are the main temples known as Atash Behrams; the remaining are the smaller temples known as agiaries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_temple#Gallery
So possibly you might want to find out whether smoke is a problem at modern fire temples and how smoke problems are mitigated.

Just a thought, but when the chimney sweeps have finished, keep the sacks of sweepings would you - I've a merchandising idea.

Yeah actually I like that too, the ash could be like "holy" and be sold off, even though there wouldn't be much if we're going with the mossstly pure ethanol idea which I really like too.

Excellent catch!  That said, examining the modern fire temples, the fire itself is very small, more of an "eternal flame" in the style popular in federal capitals, and so emissions are minimal.

Not all fire causes smoke. A "good" fire, like the one you get by burning methane, gives only water vapor and carbon dioxide. A "poor" fire, like the one you get by burning a tire or dung, produces a lot of sooth and particles too.
A temple, being a place of worship, will be designed so that it's clean and shiny, and the fire adored there must be clean too. Meaning it will be made in such a way that it won't produce smoke, in the same way many real life temples are adorned with gold and not with rust.

Smoke is a sign of incomplete/inefficient combustion. Assuming 'science' in your fantasy, the trick is to have enough incomplete combustion for the fire to be visible, but enough complete combustion for clean burns.
I'd combine a few things that 'modern' technology has/can do
You're using something similar to a Dakota fire pit - you have a series of small fires burning with excellent air intake. Maybe a series of under-ground tunnels feed the fires with the fire's own thermodynamics. Heat rises, cold air is sucked in from outside. You start with remarkably little smoke, and more fun here, you have a supply of heated air.
The heated air, more fuel, and and more fresh air, also passively drawn in, is used to generate a carefully controlled fire tornedo, which further burns the waste products and such and funnels it upwards into another chamber. Slow Mo guys has a great video of an actively powered one but it also happens in nature
Its mostly engineering, but a pillar of flame would look impressive and magical.
The heated waste air goes up into a hole in the ceiling. You can generally capture soot (with water? Maybe a series of baffles), and releasing the cleaned air out would reduce the amount of smoke.

Yeah, a well-drafted fire will have very little smoke even with a heavy, carbon-rich fuel like coal, heavy oil, or wood.  See how the Brits fired their steam locos for a great example

I just wanted a excuse for a great big pillar of fire, and kinda worked backwords from there :D

I love this and thank you for the link to the awesome fire. Yep definitely gonna make this part of the temples design this is just too cool
